# Mouse Click in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, mouseevent, mouseclick-event

I need a mouse click event in my silver light project and I know we need to simulate it ourself if the object is not button. lets say I want mouseclick for my img...
How exactly can we track time between mousedown and mouseup and say if the time between them is less than 300m, we have a mouse click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle the `MouseLeftButtonDown` and `MouseLeftButtonUp` events for your image.

```
private DateTime? startClick;

private void image1_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    startClick = DateTime.Now;
}

private void image1_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var clickDuration = DateTime.Now - startClick;

    if (startClick != null && clickDuration < TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Less than 300ms!");
    }

    startClick = null;
}
```